# Why dplyr case_when doesnt work correctly?

Tags: r, dplyr

I am working on a data frame and I want to generate a new variable conditionally based on values, but those values greater than 1 are supposed to say "Sin sentido", however, this is not the case and it still appears "En desarrollo", Does anyone know why this happens? Is there an error in the syntax of my code? Hope you can help me
The code is the following:

```
ejercicio <- data.frame(
  dato1 = c(0,0.1,0.5,1,1.1)
)


ejercicio <- ejercicio |> 
  mutate(Estatus = case_when(
    dato1 == 1 ~ "Completado",
    dato1 == 0 ~ "Sin empezar",
    dato1 > 0 | dato1 < 1 ~ "En desarrollo",
    dato1 > 1 ~ "Sin sentido"
  ))
```

Comment: Jorge, as highlighted in the answer, the "OR" is valid for all values. If you want to check for the thresholds, aka == 0 / 1, and what is between, your logical condition should be the "AND" (i.e. & := dato1 > 0 & data1 < 1) rather than an OR.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The reason is that the third condition already meets for all the rows

```
 with(ejercicio, dato1 > 0 | dato1 < 1)
[1] TRUE TRUE TRUE TRUE TRUE
```

Thus, the last condition is not evaluated.  Probably, we could change the sequence of expression i.e. the last should go above the third condition

```
ejercicio |> 
  mutate(Estatus = case_when(
    dato1 == 1 ~ "Completado",
    dato1 == 0 ~ "Sin empezar",
    dato1 > 1 ~ "Sin sentido",
    dato1 > 0 | dato1 < 1 ~ "En desarrollo"
    
  ))
```

-output

```
dato1       Estatus
1   0.0   Sin empezar
2   0.1 En desarrollo
3   0.5 En desarrollo
4   1.0    Completado
5   1.1   Sin sentido
```

NOTE: These are floats, so using `==` should be careful i.e. it may not be exactly equal unless precision is taken care of